# how to make two tcp connectinos in ios app

Tags: ios, tcp, nsstream

I am working on an ios app that needs to make tcp connections to two servers with different addresses. Does NSStream can make it, how to do that? shuold I put one communication on a separate thread?

Comment: no, is there a way if using urls?